# How to update jQuery datetimepicker based on select onChange event

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Please note this question is about **datetimepicker** NOT datepicker.

I have a **datetimepicker** that is initialised to the current date.
When user selects an option in a select element, I want to update the datetimepicker based on the selected date. Here is my code:

```
$("#date_from").datetimepicker({
    format: 'D MMM Y - H:mm',
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    stepping: 10,
    minDate: new Date()
});

$('select').on('change', function (e) {
    updating_date = this.value; // gives a value like 2019-04-06 10:30:00
    // I want to update the datetimepicker to reflect updating_date 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found a solution. Instead of updating the datetimepicker using JavaScript, I just added the updating_date as value of the date input. The datetimepicker gets this value itself and I don't need to do anything else. So, basically here is what I did:   
`$('#date_from').val(updating_date);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, you need to change the options of your `DateTimpePicker` element.

2 things to know :

- `$('#date_from').data("DateTimePicker").options()` get you all the options of your element.
- To change these options - the date in your case - you can add your new datetime in the paramater of the `option` method.

> Info on this link :
>   https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#date

```
    $('select').on('change', function (e) {
        var updating_date = new Date('2019-04-06 10:30:00');
          $('#date_from')
              .data("DateTimePicker")
              .options({
                    'date': updating_date
               });
    });
```

**Snippet**

```js
$("#date_from").datetimepicker({
    format: 'D MMM Y - H:mm',
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    stepping: 10,
    minDate: new Date()
});

$('select').on('change', function (e) {
    var updating_date = new Date('2019-04-06 10:30:00');
    //console.log($('#date_from').data("DateTimePicker").options());
        $('#date_from')
      .data("DateTimePicker")
      .options({
      'date': updating_date});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select>
  <option value="">Monday</option>
  <option value="">Friday</option>
</select>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='date_from'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Bahman yes, I did. See the snippet in the updated answer. Do you have any error/warning when you tried it ?

Comment: It just didn't do anything, but I got no error. I will try your code again this afternoon and will get back to you. thank you anyway.